# Can't get message body of certain emails from inbox using the Zend framework?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, imap

I am trying to read through an email inbox for my application - I'm using the zend framework here. The problem is that I'm unable to retrieve the message body for certain emails. The following is my code as to how I'm doing this:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($mail_options);

$all_messages = array();

$page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1;
$limit = isset($_GET['limit'])?$_GET['limit']:20;

$offset = (($page-1)*$limit)+1;

$end = ($page*$limit)>$c?$c:($page*$limit);
for ($i=$offset;$i<=$end;$i++){

    $h2t = new html2text();
    $h2t->set_allowed_tags('<a>');

    if(!$mail[$i])
        break;
    else{
        $one_message = $mail->getMessage($i);
        $one_message->id = $i;
        $one_message->UID = $mail->getUniqueId($i);

        $one_message->parts = array();
        $one_message->body = '';
        $count = 1;
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($mail->getMessage($i)) as $ii=>$part) {

            try {
                $tpart = $part;
                //$tpart->_content = '';
                $one_message->parts[$count] =  $tpart;
                $count++;
                // check for html body
                if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/html') {
                    $b = $part->getContent();

                    if($part->contentTransferEncoding == 'quoted-printable')
                        $b = quoted_printable_decode($b);

                    $one_message->html_body = $b;
                    $h2t->set_html($b);
                    $one_message->body = $h2t->get_text();
                }

                //check for text body

                if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/plain') {
                    $b = $part->getContent();

                    if($part->contentTransferEncoding == 'quoted-printable')
                        $b = quoted_printable_decode($b);

                    $one_message->text_body = $b;

                    $one_message->body = $b;//$part->getContent();
                }

            } catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e) {
                // ignore
            }

        }

        $all_messages[] = $one_message;

    }
}
```

The problem is that randomly some messages don't return even a textbody or an html body. Even though if I check using a webvmail client those emails have a message body as well. WHat am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the mail is multipart message first, before looping over the parts. If it's not multipart, then the body will be exposed via `$mail->getContent()` instead of a part. Basic example:

```
if ($mail->isMultiPart()) {
     // Multipart messages handled here
     foreach() {
        // loop over parts
     }
} else {
     // Non multipart messages handled here

     // default text_body
     $one_message->text_body = $mail->getContent();

     if (strtok($msg->contentType, ';') == 'text/html') {
         // HTML email with no plain text alternative, set both values
         $one_message->body = $mail->getContent();
         $one_message->text_body = strip_tags($mail->getContent());
     }
}
```