# Zend Mail message content

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu, pop3, zend-mail

I am using Zend Mail in order to get a list of email messages from my POP3 server, and display it on a web page. Here is my code:

```
<?

require("Zend/Mail/Storage/Pop3.php");

$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3(array('host'     => 'localhost',
                                         'user'     => 'person',
                                         'password' => 'awesome'));

// show the mail!

echo "You have " . $mail->countMessages() . " messages! <br><br>";

foreach ($mail as $message) {
  echo "From: '{$message->from}'<br> Subject: {$message->subject}<br>";
  echo "Content: " . $message->getContent() . "<br><br>";
}

?>
```

The problem is that some of the emails are showing up like this:

```
    From: 'Trey '
Subject: WOMBATS WOMBATS
Content: --Apple-Mail-1--609821059 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii SWIMMING IN THE OCEAN CAUSIN' A COMOTION CUZ THEY SUCK --Apple-Mail-1--609821059 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii SWIMMING IN THE OCEAN 
CAUSIN' A COMOTION 
CUZ THEY 
SUCK
--Apple-Mail-1--609821059--
```

which makes it hard to read the actual body content of the message. I want it to show up like this:

```
From: 'Stan Flusterflap '
Subject: hi
Content: hi
```

How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to do something about that whole wombat infestation thing.

Answer (score 3):

The `getContent` method gets the *entire* message body.  What you're seeing there is the entire body, composed of two MIME parts and their separators.

[There's an example in the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) -- search for "multipart part" -- of how to work with [the MIME parts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mime.part.html) directly.

Comment: Right. You might have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749772/cant-get-message-body-of-certain-emails-from-inbox-using-the-zend-framework too